# Node.js SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have defined the routers for the api as follows, one for the post and get,

```
var bookRouter = express.Router();
bookRouter.route('/Books')
    .post(function(req, res) {
        var bok = new book(req.body);
        console.log(bok);
        res.send(bok);

    })
   .get(function(req, res) {
    var query = req.query;
    book.find(query, function(err, books) {
        if (err)
            res.status(500).send(err);
        else
            res.json(books);
    });

});
```

it throws an error saying `'.get(function(req, res) {'` `Unexpected token .`

**Node version :**
v4.3.0

Parser used :
body-parser

Comment: Can you provide some details of your environment? Like node version, parser used (if any) etc.

Comment: node version is 4.3.0 , i have used body-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Ruoter();
router.post("/Books",function(req,res){
    var bok = new book(req.body);
    console.log(bok);
    res.send(bok);
});
router.get("/Book/?id",function(req.res){
var query = req.params.id;
book.find(query, function(err, books) {
    if (err)
        res.status(500).send(err);
    else
        res.json(books);
})
```

Comment: What was the OP's problem, and how does this fix it?

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer.

Comment: i worte it in my way , all the change is req.params.id